# NextJS 14 App Router Mongoose issue MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

The problem is that when the code runs sometime to runs successfully and some times it gives error MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations.any solution?

```
export async function DeleteProductBySlug({ slug, storeId }: any) {
  const databaseUri: string = process.env.DATABASE_URI as string;
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(databaseUri);

    const StoreProduct: any = await ProductsModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { storeId: storeId },
      { $pull: { products: { slug: slug } } },
      { new: true }
    );
    if (StoreProduct) {
      revalidatePath(`/${storeId}/product/allproducts`);
      return true;
    }
    console.log("server");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("DELETE", error);
    return false;
  } finally {
    await mongoose.disconnect();
  }
}
```